# How to soft reset Chisel Counter

Tags: chisel

I'm using a Chisel Counter in my logic, and want to be able to reset it also on clear input signal.
how can i do that ?
I was thinking of something like that:

```
withReset(reset || io.clr) {val (count,wrap) = Counter(io.valid,512)}
```

My Issue with this (apart from being ugly) is that the val names are not available out of the scope of the withReset.
Is there a better way to do so ?
How about trying to assign `0.U` the inner value of the Counter , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`withReset` returns the last expression in the block](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.3.0/chisel3/withReset$.html), so you can just write:

```scala
val (count, wrap) =  withReset(reset.asBool || io.clr)(Counter(io.valid,512))
```

Note that I added `.asBool` to `reset` because in `import chisel3._`, `val reset` has the abstract type `Reset`. See the [Chisel website docs on `Reset`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/reset.html) for more information.

I think the above is the best way to do it, but you can also use the [`@chiselName` macro](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/experimental/package$$chiselName.html) to allow Chisel to name vals inside scopes:

```scala
import chisel3.experimental.chiselName

@chiselName
class MyModule extends Module {
  ...


  withReset(reset || io.clr) {val (count,wrap) = Counter(io.valid,512)}
  //                               ^ these ^ will now get named
}
```

Note that we're trying to get a better version of `@chiselName` into the `3.4.0` release in the coming weeks, but `@chiselName` works for the time being.